# Handle event in VsPackage

Tags: visual-studio, events, vspackage

I need to handle the text selection changed event in the Vspackage , i did a ton of google search and did not find any clue on how to do that , it seems very reasonable and should be very easy to do , not only is the documentation very bad , but none of microsoft samples on this topic show how to handle events . 
I would appreciate if any one has done this before and can provide me with the code .

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if such an event exists; what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quick answer and should get you going.

```
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
internal sealed class SelectionCreatio : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{
    public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
    {
        textView.Selection.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // do your stuff.
        }

    }
}
```

Mark your VSPackage as a MEF component and you're good to go.

Comment: Hello Erti Chris
I think you nailed it  , but honestly i dont know how to use this code ?
How do  i use this class from within my package ? 
Also how to mark VSPackage as a MEF component .
Thanks a lot for the time you spent working on this .